# Ruby on Rails: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am using Active Record outside rails. I created one rb file at

```
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/bin/process.rb
```

Code of process.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activerecord'

require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "root123",
  :database => "testproject_development"
)
```

But when i run this rb file then i get the following error:-

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@artwork_auto/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext/parser.so: 
[BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

from here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4411143

try changing your shebang to to keep your versions from getting mixed up.

{{{

## !/usr/bin/env ruby

}}}